# Write Data to Worksheet Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newbie in VBA and I have this issue. I have this command button on my Excelsheet:

Command button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim TestCell As String
    TestCell = Range("A1").Value
    TestCell = "Test"
End Sub
```

I wonder why this code doesn't work for me.

PS: Of course it works when I use: `Range("A1").Value = "Test"`, but for some reason I need to use `TestCell = Range("A1").Value` (Variable used as cell reference).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?.. Do you want to write **"Test"** in `Range("A1")`? Why is it `TestCell = Range("A1").Value` and the other way around (`Range("A1").Value = TestCell`)?

Comment: Yes, but I need to use a variable as cell reference

Comment: It will be `TestCell = Range("A1").Address : Range(TestCell).Value = "Test"` if I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Range variable if you want a reference to the cell instance. Then use it to read or write values.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim TestCell As Range
Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
Set TestCell = ws.Range("A1")
TestCell.Value = "Test"
```

Comment: A side note, always set ws(worksheet) reference and use it to point cell ranges. Never trust on an implicit reference(without ws object). You thank me later when your VBA apps get more complex.